# ReferenceError: is saying Cannot access 'user' before initialization in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, api, mongoose

> I am making an api and i want to store the post information in the database in Postman. I have created a server.js, userControllers.js, userRoutes and userModels.js but when I try and post the data to Postman I get this error below:
>
> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user'
> before initialization
> at C:\Users\drago\OneDrive\Documents\Third Year College\Cryptonia\server\controllers\userControllers.js:7:24
>
> I dont know why when I go to postman this error wont go away i think it has something to do with the User.findOne(); in userController I go to this and have seen the code has been written properly and there was no problems before when i was sending the data for name and email now when I try it im just receving these errros down below any help will be much apprecciated and if you know how to resolve this please help as this will be of much benefit to me.

```
    const asyncHandler = require('express-async-handler');
const User = require('../models/userModel');

const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, pic } = req.body;

    const userExists = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (userExists) {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('User already Exists');
    }

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        pic,
    });


    if (user) {
        res.status(201).json({
            _id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
            pic: user.pic,
        })
    } else {
        res.status(400)
        throw new Error('Error Occured');
    }

    res.json({
        name,
        email,
    });
});

module.exports = { registerUser };
```

``
//userModel

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
        },
        isAdmin: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true,
            default: false,
        },
        pic: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default:
                "https://icon-library.com/images/anonymous-avatar-icon/anonymous-avatar-icon-25.jpg",
        },
    },
    {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

``

Comment: I see this error when I try to use a module before importing it. Can you share the full source for those files, include the imports? I'm guessing something in your `asyncHandler` file is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks but its fine now I've figured out how to fix this errow I'll leave how i done it down below for anyone whos going through this in the future